# Ansible: how to copy env file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible

I am trying to copy `docker-compose` file and an `env` file on the remote server but ansible is able to copy docker-compose file but it doesn't seem to work for the env file.

Here is the error that i am getting:-

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option
fatal: [10.19.x.x]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '/home/ubuntu/git/files/env' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

This is my ansible playbook:-

```
---

- name: Write docker-compose files
  become: yes
  copy:
    src: /home/ubuntu/git/files/docker-compose.yml
    dest: /home/remote/docker-compose.yml

- name: Write env files
  become: yes
  copy:
    src: /home/ubuntu/git/files/env
    dest: /home/remote/env


- name: Run docker service
  become: yes
  docker_compose:
    project_src: /home/remote/
```

This is my output when i run the ansible playbook:-

```
PLAY [configure redash-server] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 16.04 on host 10.19.x.x should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will
 default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature will be removed in 
version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [10.19.x.x]

TASK [redash-version-8 : Write docker-compose files] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.19.x.x]

TASK [redash-version-8 : Write env files] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option
fatal: [10.19.x.x]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '/home/psharma/git/files/env' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.19.x.x                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and running the latest version of ansible ( 2.9.12 ). Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you're using the correct file path/file name? Might it be `.env` instead of `env`?

In case the file name and path are correct, a possibility might be that the file permissions on the file are incorrect. If this is a personal computer you could perhaps try changing permissions for the env file using something like `chmod 777 env` in the correct directory.

In any case, the output of `ls -al` in the directory `/home/ubuntu/git/files/` might be helpful to look further into the issue.

Comment: Wow!! My env file had a typo in it. Thank you sir.